# Yii 1.* зарегистрировать css

Tags: yii

Как зарегистрировать  css? Пробую из `protected/css`

```
Yii::app()->getClientScript()->registerCssFile(Yii::app()->basePath . '/css/exadata.css');
```

не получается

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно хранить файлы в папке protected/assets, в ней css, js, images и тогда можно делать примерно так:

```
$_assets = Yii::app()->assetManager->publish(
                Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.assets'), 
                false,
                -1,
                YII_DEBUG
            );
Yii::app()->getClientScript()->registerCssFile($_assets . '/css/exadata.css');
```

Comment: Я так сделал $path = Yii::app()->assetManager->publish(Yii::app()->basePath . '/css/');
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCssFile($path . '/exadata.css');

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что Yii::app()->basePath указывает на корень приложения в **файловой системе**. Этот путь нужен когда мы работаем с файлами внутри приложения (к примеру сохраняем картинки и пр).
Для регистрации css или js из корневой папки (или подпапки) этот параметр лишний, а значит в Вашем случае, если exadata.css лежит в подпапке /css 
или так

```
Yii::app()->getClientScript()->registerCssFile(Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/css/exadata.css');
```

или так

```
Yii::app()->getClientScript()->registerCssFile('/css/exadata.css');
```

Разница будет в выводе в коде HTML. В первом случае будет 
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://domain.com/css/exadata.css" />` во втором случае `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/exadata.css" />`

Оба варианта вполне себе рабочие.

Что касается варианта регистрации через CAssetManager::publish, то тут есть несколько подводных камней. В варианте, предложенном bemulima, то надо учитывать следующие моменты

```
Yii::app()->assetManager->publish(
            Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.assets'), 
            false,
            -1,
            YII_DEBUG
        );
```

Тут указанно, что публикуется вся папка assets (копируется), копируется вся, включая подкаталоги, и в режиме YII_DEBUG она переписывается постоянно. Но если надо будет сделать изменения на сервере, в режиме PRODUCTION, то надо будет не только залить изменения файлов в protected/assets, но и почистить папку /assets потому-что:

> При публикации папки, её содержимое копируется рекурсивно. При этом метод проверяет только наличие папки с таким же именем, но не отдельных ресурсов. То есть при изменении ресурсов в этой папке её содержимое заново опубликовано не будет.

Второй момент - избыточное кол-во файлов-ресурсов на сервере. Зачем вам две копии файла exadata.css на сервере? Публикация ресурсов полезна в следующих случаях:

- При оформлении кода как расширения, ресурсы которого содержатся в той же папке, что и код.
- При использовании ресурсов за корнем вебсервера.
- Для обработки ресурсов непосредственно перед публикацией. Например, сжатия CSS и JavaScript.
- При использовании одного и того же ресурса множеством компонент (для исключения дубликатов).

Если хотя-бы один из пунктов удовлетворяет вашему условию - используйте публикацию, иначе используйте регистрацию в примере, что я привел. Хорошего кода!